# Python join - quoting values

Tags: python

I am using the Python join function to create a string e.g.

```
a = [a, b, c, d]
b = ",".join(a)
print b

b = a,b,c,d
```

but I want

```
b = 'a','b','c','d'
```

is there a way to do this just using the join function (or a shorter way) rather than doing

```
b = ""
for x in a:
  b += "'%s'," % x
b = b[:-1]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [1]: a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

In [2]: print ','.join("'%s'" % x for x in a)
'a','b','c','d'
```

Answer (score 9):

```
b = ",".join(map(repr, a))
```

Will also correctly escape characters inside the string which may be useful.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> print ','.join("'{0}'".format(s) for s in b)
'a','b','c','d'
```

The expression inside the join() is a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions).

Answer (score 5):

```
b = "'" + "','".join(a) + "'"
```

:)

Comment: Although this works correctly, it is not the most logical solution.

Comment: Agreed, but it's probably the most space- and time-efficient solution. And since it's really just a one-liner, I wouldn't worry about the conceptual complexity too much...

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

b = "','".join(a).join("''")
```